# Gradle Script - Wait action finished before file.delete()

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, unzip

With gradle I'm downloading a zipfile with an API. After that I'm unzipping this file and next I want delete it.

I tried many thing for that, but couldn't find the right solution.

I'm very begginner with Gradle syntax (doLast, doFirst).

```
task downloadAndDelete(type: Copy) {
        doLast {
            blablabla
            def zipFile = file(pathFile + fileName)
            println '-------- Download zipfile --------'
            blablabla
            from zipTree(zipFile)
            into pathFile
            println '-------- Deleting zipfile --------'
            zipFile.delete()
        }
    }
```

Sometimes I have an error `Cannot convert path to File. path='property (@OutputDirectory destinationDir) for task 'downloadUpdatedStrings''`
Sometimes I my zipFile is deleted before finished to unzip.

How can I delete my zipFile after be sure this one finished to unzip.
I tried also with [`'unzip', '-o', zipFile, '-d', pathFile].execute()`, but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a task for each of the three steps (`download`, `unzip` and `delete`):

```
task downloadMyFile {
    doLast {
         // somehow download your file, e.g.
         file('myFile.zip') << new URL("http://some.url/some/path/file.zip").getText()
    }
}

task unzipMyFile(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn downloadMyFile
    from zipTree('myfile.zip')
    into 'target/path'
    finalizedBy deleteMyFile
}

task deleteMyFile(type: Delete) {
    mustRunAfter unzipMyFile
    delete downloadMyFile
}
```

Now it is sufficient to call `unzipMyFile` (or use it as input for another task) to execute all tasks.

Please note, that normally it is not required to delete files after you used them. Just put them anywhere in your `build` directory and the next `clean` operation will delete it anyhow.

Comment: I got an error : 
`Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: task ':app:downloadMyFile'.
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - A String or CharSequence path, for example 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'.
    - A String or CharSequence URI, for example 'file:/usr/include'.
    - A File instance.
    - A Path instance.
    - A Directory instance.
    - A RegularFile instance.
    - A URI or URL instance.
`
The error says the line where i do `from zipTree(downloadMyFile)`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that `zipTree` can't handle tasks directly, so I replaced it with the file and added the task dependency manually.